# Setdiff within mutate function

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a data frame with three columns. Each row contains three unique numbers between 1 and 5 (inclusive).

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,4,2),
                 b=c(5,3,1),
                 c=c(3,1,5))
```

I want to use mutate to create two additional columns that, for each row, contain the two numbers between 1 and 5 that do not appear in the initial three columns in ascending order. The desired data frame in the example would be:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,4,2),
                  b=c(5,3,1),
                  c=c(3,1,5),
                  d=c(2,2,3),
                  e=c(4,5,4))
```

I tried to use the below mutate function utilizing setdiff to accomplish this, but returned NAs rather than the values I was looking for:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(d=setdiff(c(a,b,c),c(1:5))[1],
                    e=setdiff(c(a,b,c),c(1:5))[2])
```

I can get around this by looping through each row (or using an apply function) but would prefer a mutate approach if possible.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```r
cbind(df, t(apply(df, 1, setdiff, x = 1:5)))
#   a b c 1 2
# 1 1 5 3 2 4
# 2 4 3 1 2 5
# 3 2 1 5 3 4
```

Warning: if there are any non-numerical columns, `apply` will happily up-convert things (converting to a matrix internally).

Comment: I appreciate your desire to use `mutate`, but ... it's the wrong function for this job. I don't care if you "must" use tidyverse verbs or not, but regardless, make sure you use the right tool for the job. In this case, it is certainly more succinct to generate the columns externally and `cbind`/`bind_cols` them to your original frame later. In this case (admittedly very small data), this base R solution is well over an order of magnitude *faster* than the tidyverse answer provided ...

Comment: Perhaps there is a more canonical approach to this using the tidyverse, but ... sometimes it's easier to just use base R. The typical tidyverse way to do it will be either explicitly or implicitly using `rowwise()`, which can be ghastly slower than things that work on the object as a whole.

Comment: I agree with the statement regarding speed on larger data sets (my real dataset is 500k rows) and for that reason am accepting this answer, which worked in ~10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap` to loop over the rows, create a `list` column and then `unnest` it to create two new columns

```
library(dplyr)
librayr(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(out = pmap(., ~ setdiff(1:5, c(...)) %>% 
                 as.list%>% 
                 set_names(c('d', 'e')))) %%>% 
   unnest_wider(c(out))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#      a     b     c     d     e
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1     1     5     3     2     4
#2     4     3     1     2     5
#3     2     1     5     3     4
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[c('d', 'e')] <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(asplit(df, 1), function(x) setdiff(1:5, x)))
```

Comment: I learned about `asplit` today ... nice ... *no idea* how it has avoided me all this time ...